# How to check if an array is a plain built-in Array?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Given that anyone can extend built-in types now, how to I properly check, if a given Array is a real plain old base JavaScript Array and not some extended version?

What I tried:

```
arr instanceof Array // true for child classes, too
Array.isArray(arr)   // same
```

Is there another way?

Comment: The whole point of using class inheritance is to create new kinds of objects that, by inheriting from other classes, will operate like the parent class for APIs that expect those parents. By checking the "type" you're defeating the purpose. What is it that you don't want subclassed Array objects to do?

Comment: I have to check if a passed Array is a plain array so I can wrap it. Simple...

Comment: @Fuzzyma What do you mean by "wrap it"? Why don't you want to wrap other arrays?

Comment: I do want to wrap other arrays. Dont need to do it when its already wrapped

Comment: @Fuzzyma In that case you should only check whether it is already wrapped (i.e. `instanceof MyArrayWrapper`), instead of checking whether it is plain array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't be absolutely sure, but unless the person providing the object to you is actively trying to mislead you, you can do this:

```
if (arr.constructor === Array) {
    // Yes, it is
}
```

**But**, beware: If you get `arr` from another *realm* (such as a child or parent window), that check will be false, because `arr.constructor` will refer to the `Array` constructor in that other realm, which is not `===` the `Array` constructor in *your* realm.

If you need it to be a plain array and `arr` may be from another realm, you probably want to copy it:

```
arr = Array.from(arr);
```

---

Another option that comes to mind is this:

```js
function isReallyAPlainArray(arr) {
    const getProto = Object.getPrototypeOf;
    try {
        // A plain array's prototype is Array.prototype, whose prototype is
        // Object. prototype, whose prototype is null
        return Array.isArray(arr) && getProto(getProto(getProto(arr))) === null;
    } catch (e) {
        // Prototype chain was too short; not a plain array
        return false;
    }
}


class MyArray extends Array { }

console.log(isReallyAPlainArray([]));          // true
console.log(isReallyAPlainArray(new MyArray)); // false
```

That works because a plain array's prototype is `Array.prototype`, whose prototype is `Object.prototype`, whose prototype is `null`. If `arr` were an instance of a subclass, there'd be another layer in there. And that works cross-realm. It can *also* be defeated by someone actively trying to mislead you (by using `Object.setPrototypeOf`), but...